# Electron how to redirect users between various .html files

Tags: electron

I am looking to try to redirect users from "home.html" to "dashboard.html". I've searched far and wide, yet I haven't found an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating your window with the [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window) module, you would have used the method [win.loadFile(filePath[, options])](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options) to load your html file.

Once the logic to change pages is successful, all you need to do is execute the [win.loadFile(filePath[, options])](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options) line of code again with the path to your new file.

> As [win.loadFile(filePath[, options])](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options) returns a promise, let's add a `.then()` statement as well (though not requried).

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

const nodePath = require("path");

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('home.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

// Run when logic to change to dashboard is successful.
function showDashboard() {
    window.loadFile('dashboard.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); })
}
```